# Viewer for GNU TexInfo documentation, like `info ls`

Tags: linux, gui, command-line, documentation-viewer

The viewer for the **most detailed documentation** of the GNU tools, `info`, is not very comfortable for someone not used to `emacs`.
 There seem to be various **other viewers** available, some specialized info viewers, some more generic **hypertext viewers/browsers** that also support GNU TexInfo, the info format.
Both **GUI** and **terminal programs** are of interest.

GNU TexInfo is a hypertext format, like HTML; but viewers that linearize the page could be also interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect solution, but you can use `evil-mode` on Emacs to get `vim` keybindings and run Info using `M-x info`.

Comment: However, I found that it's easier to simply learn the info keybindings by going through the info manual. (Press `h` in `info`.)